# ErrorException: foreach() argument must be of type array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to print data from a table in the DB, but it throws me the following error when I loop through it with a `foreach()`.

> foreach () argument must be of type array | object, null given

I understand that there is a call limit. For example, when I use a `dd()` function with more than 86 data, the attributes are not printed. However, when I limit it, it displays, but the array keeps throwing the same error when traversing it and obviously its category

**Controller**

```
$preguntas = AutomatizacionPruebas::where('category_id', 4)->limit(50)->get();

return view('verPreguntas', ['preguntas' => $preguntas]);
```

**HTML**

```
@foreach ($preguntas as $pregunta)
    <ol>
       <h4>{{$pregunta->pregunta}}</h4>
       @foreach(json_decode($pregunta->opciones) as $opcion)
          <li>{{$opcion}}</li>
       @endforeach  
    </ol>
@endforeach
```

EDIT: When I try another category with 136 questions it works, but with certain categories it doesn't.
The format is similar, the only thing that changes would be the name of the question and its options

Comment: Use `json_decode($pregunta->opciones, true)` to decode to an array. See https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters

Comment: Not work. The problem is not json_decode because if I do the decode before the foreach it returns an array.

Comment: According to `foreach`, it does not.

Comment: I know but it is xD

Comment: When I try with other categories works but with two categories don't work and it's the same structure

Comment: It looks like _some_ of your `$preguntas` entries do not have valid JSON in their `opciones` properties so `json_decode()` is returning `null`. Do some debugging to find out what the values actually are

Comment: That's right, I made a mistake with the quotes. Thanks!

Comment: Please check your json data there might be something wrong with json data, else all code is proper as per foreach.
You can use this link to validate the json: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in one of the rows of the json stored in the database. The PHP code was correct so far.